# How do I store a bit of data inside a video file so it does not get stripped by other tools when sharing

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an app that takes videos and I need to store the exact creation time (down to milliseconds) inside the video. The video is then shared through whatever app the user wants in order to reach a software tool that adds some telemetry overlay on top of the video based on the exact creation time that I've set.

Setting the creation_time metadata tag does not help because apps like Whatsapp remove all metadata and compress the video.

Is there a way to store the exact creation time somewhere inside the video/audio stream itself? Or maybe create a new stream just for this? The software tool can be modified to look wherever I end up storing this value. Any other ideas?

Comment: You might be able to insert it as a text based subtitle stream, but even that may well get removed by whatever conversion system your application uses. The only real way to guarantee it still exists would be to bake it into the video somehow, as mentioned below potentially in a couple of frames at the start of the video.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, not possible unless you store the video and share a download link.

Long answer: The moment a video is recompressed, it is recreated from the ground up. This makes it impossible to reliably store information that is kept while also hide the same information from the viewer.

The solution is going to be to store the video with metadata in a place you manage, and get a download link to that video and share that link rather than sharing the video as a file itself. If people share the link, nothing can change its content.

The softwaretool will have to download the video to do its thing, and then have to upload their version and share a link to it to ensure that compression does not alter their version in any unsatisfying way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Some follow-up questions:

1. What if I use a LTC audio stream? 
2. Another option would be to add a black frame in the video with a QR code. But how do I make sure that the video frame is not being removed when the other 3rd parties compress the video? Should I have like x num of consecutive black frames to ensure that at least one survives?
3. Can I somehow piggyback on some of the fixed metadata tags? I see major_brand, minor_version and compatible_brands are being kept. Can I somehow append to one of these values?

Comment: audio streams will also be compressed, you can lose the data there too. Adding a video frame should work, but the compression can alter the appearance of this frame causing the QR code to no longer work. You should at least add a keyframe to that QR code frame which should hopefully be enough, but that also means a viewer will see the QR code or a flash. Not ideal. As for using the other fixed metatags, dunno.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said whether you care if the user knows that the code is present / if you want to prevent manual removal.

Assuming you don't care if the user knows and you only care that the code isn't removed by automatic processing such as recompression there are plenty of options, for example:

- Add a full screen QR code for 1 second at the start of the video - there are different complexities of QR codes depending upon the amount of data you want to encode if you only have a small amount of data it will probably survive compression better.
- You could go old school and use a bar code in a similar fashion.
- Add a wide bar (say 10 px) down the entire side of the image.
- Add a sequence of tones to the audio track.

Compression/recompression only strips fine details from the video/audio stream, if your encoding is large/obvious most likely it will survive recompression without issue.

If you control the app and want to hide the encoding from the user you just need to take the appropriate action in the app - for example skip forward 1 second before starting the playback to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's OK-ish if the user knows that the code is present. It's for his own benefit after all. How would I encode the wide bar with the info so that the software tool can read it? It's just a string representing the exact creation timestamp. Similarly, can you point me into the right direction for "Add a sequence of tones to the audio track." ?

Comment: I am not aware of specific implementations that are designed to work with video transcoding, my assumption is that you can leverage older tech from other domains for example for the tones you could look at how telephone exchanges recognize tones from touch tone phone (or maybe the digital modes used in HAM radio) for encoding the bits in a sidebar in the video I would start by looking at "Manchester Code" since if you need to send more than one frame you need to effectively encode a clock signal to allow for differences in playback speed / jitter.